# Where to get raw data for ESA graphs

Tags: debris, esa

The European Space Agency maintains the MASTER space debris model and has multiple papers published on the topic.

There is a graph that I have seen in a few papers and on a few websites that I would like to obtain the raw data for to assist with my current research.

[image: Chart]

There is an entry for it in their multimedia archives [here](https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Images/2017/04/Debris_object_evolution). However, there's no obvious link to obtain the raw data.

Would anyone have any idea where I could start on my search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data comes from [DISCOS (Database and Information System Characterising Objects in Space)](https://sdup.esoc.esa.int).

You can get access [here](https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int), but:

> Users with a demonstrated need-to-know can apply for an account for on-line use (specified quotas apply) of DISCOS through a dedicated web-interface, if they belong to a research institute, to a government organisation, or to an industrial company of an ESA Member State (e.g., not as an individual).

Comment: You absolute legend... I have no idea how you knew about that but thank you

Comment: @Persistence I have a very carefully crafted and nurtured Google bubble.